# Disable display of x and y values on ChartJS

Tags: chart.js

For some reasons I have X and Y values showing up on my line chart as follows, but they are unexpected.

[image]

```
<canvas id="chartTimeline" height="28"></canvas>

<script>
    const img = new Image(16, 16);
img.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q94Tt.png'; 

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartTimeline').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: [
        { x: "2020-03-22", y: 0 },
        { x: "2020-04-01", y: 0 },
        { x: "2020-04-02", y: 0 },
        { x: "2020-04-03", y: 0 },
        { x: "2020-04-08", y: 0 },
        { x: "2020-04-12", y: 0 },
        { x: "2020-04-15", y: 0 }
      ],
      pointStyle: img,
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
      legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          display: false,
        },        
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'day',
          tooltipFormat: 'MMM DD'
        },
        gridLines: {
          display:false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});</script>
```

As per my understanding of chartJS options, theses values should not appear. There are no errors popping in the console.

I wonder, what is this called ? Why is it being displayed ? How can I disable it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the datalabels plugin, it was generating these values automatically.